# How to update Thunderbird to latest version?

Tags: 13.04, updates, thunderbird

I have ubuntu 13.04 and my Thunderbird version is 24.0. Now Mozilla released 24.1. How can I update to it?

Comment: Your question applies to all Ubuntu software. See http://askubuntu.com/q/151283/88802